# Is there a way to prevent Google App Engine from restarting instances due to (faux) http errors?

Tags: google-app-engine, http

My Google App Engine application returns 503 codes to clients when they should try later to receive data from the server.  This appears to cause app engine to think the application is failing and after several such responses the instance is restarted, adding to average latency.  Is there a way to prevent app engine from restarting instances just because you manually return 503 or other non-200 http response codes?  TIA!

**Edit 1:**
Here's a screenshot of how it typically goes (with some app-specific stuff ablated due to the sensitive nature of my app).  Note that all the [I]nformational and [D]ebug messages are generated by my code, while the [W]arning about the restart is obviously GAE itself.   The only thing that distinguishes the times this happens is when I return a 503.

[image]

Comment: Since there is no obvious setting, and I'd have to re-engineer my GAE app and the non-GAE client code that access it to experiment without using 503, I have not really been able to try anything.  Fair question, though.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>App Engine doesn't base decisions to terminate or restart instances based on the status codes you return, or on what you log.</strike>

It seems App Engine now does base instancing decisions on your return code. To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to return a 5xx code, but tell App Engine that nothing's really wrong.

Comment: Thanks Nick. But, do you have any ideas of what else could cause the instance to decide to restart itself after it handles "too many sequential errors."  I've attached a screenshot of a typical example.  Are there known situations that cause this? Thanks!